# .htaccess redirect with exception

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In one of my projects I'm trying to redirect using .htaccess. I am using a redirect like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

But, now I'd like to add an exception to the rewrite rules. I want http://example.com/admin/ to be redirected in the same way, only to a different directory. All of the other traffic should still go to the public directory. So i added a rewrite condition like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

This didn't do the trick. I am still being redirected to the public folder. I also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/ [L]
RewriteRule admin(.*) admin/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

This only made things worse. I now get an 500 internal server error.

I have been searching for hours now, and I'm getting a bit tired of finding examples that show how to add an exception for a certain folder, but don't show how to redirect this traffic to another folder. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong, or which other approach I could try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `RewriteCond` only applies to *the rule directly beneath it*. In other words, in your example, it's only applied to the empty path rule. Move the `RewriteCond` down one notch, and it will work better.

```
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Additionally, I find your rule

```
RewriteRule admin(.*) admin/$1 [L]
```

to be odd. A URL like `/adminsomething` will be rewritten to `/admin/something` which I don't think is what you want.

Furthermore I have a hunch that you're confusing a *rewrite* with a *redirect*. A rewrite is a rule that makes a request be rewritten internally and interpreted differently. A redirect is a rule that will tell the visitor's browser to go to a different address. Which one are you going for?

The magic keyword for a *redirect* is `R=301` which means redirect with http code 301 Moved Permanently. For example, you may want to try...

```
# This first rule is actually redundant in this case so skip it...
#RewriteRule ^$ public/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The admin thing was just a typo. I forgot the slash. I moved the RewriteCond down one rule and everything works as I want it to. I think I was looking for a rewrite rule, because it should be handeled internally.